# Когда нужно связывать таблицы БД?

Tags: sql

в БД Имеется таблицы спрВузов(колонки id_wuz, name_wuz ), спрГородов(id_gorod, name_gorod), спрЛюдей( id_chelovek, name_chelovek, surname)

В программе нужно сделать такую таблицу, где пользователи могли бы вводить Нового Студента, город в котором проживает этот студент и в каком ВУЗ-е он учиться:
id_student,name_student, name_gorod, name_wuz.

Хочу понять, какой самый правильный путь, что бы получить такую таблицу-нужно связать мои справочники или это самый короткий путь?

Comment: Видимо, нужно почитать про внешние ключи.

Comment: Если с течением времени один и тот же человек не может учится в разных вузах или переезжать. Или может, но нас интересует только текущая информация. То в справочнике людей добавляем колонки id_gorod и id_wuz. Если же надо знать когда куда человек перезжал и где учился, то тогда места учебы и места проживания выносить в отдельные таблицы вида id_chlovek, id_gorod(wuz) ну и интервалы дат с какого по какое число он там жил/учился

Answer (score 3):

Если вам нужно указывать в каком городе проживает студент, то  можно сделать одну таблицу с внешними ключами от трех справочников.

Я не вижу всех условий задачи, но хотелось бы уточнить, что место проживания студента *(в общем случае)* зависит не от студента, а от города, в котором расположен университет. Также университеты часто могут отличаться только городом размещения *(филиалы)*.
Поэтому мое предложение состоит в следующем:
Создать таблицу с внешними ключами от таблиц списка городов и списка Вузов *(на схеме - Университет)*. Теперь построить зависимость между списком людей и таблицей университетов с помощью таблицы Студент.

[image: Пример схемы БД]